# semantic highlighting issue vscode windows 10

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-10, syntax-highlighting

I have problems with semantic highlighting in vscode, it is nothing serious but the truth is that it is awful and after spending two days looking for how to solve the problem I have not achieved anything, so I have decided to ask around here.
The problem is that when installing vscode on windows the semantic highlighting it worked:
[semantic highlighting working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj2Mq.png)
however after closing and opening the application or starting a new window, the semantic highlighting stops working:
[semantic highlighting not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTNap.png).
This does not happen in a virtual machine that I have with ubuntu, I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the python extension, I have also tried to install the user version and the system version, but I get the same problem for both versions. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: try   file-->preferences--->color theme--->Dark+ (default Dark)

Comment: @virxen, 
I have also tried that, I tried precisely after reading an answer here to a similar question

Comment: file-->preferences-->settings  and search for color theme.look there if you find the problem

Comment: @virxen, apparently I don't see anything weird, dark + is set (default dark)

Answer (score 1):

I tried some Themes in my VSCode:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And you can custom it manually in the settings.json file:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "functions": "#0077ff",
    "comments": "#0004ff",
    "keywords": "#c8ff00",
    "numbers": "#ff00ea",
    "strings": "#FF0000",
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "source.python meta.function-call.python",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#72f1b8",
          "fontStyle": "bold"
        }
      }
    ],
    "types": "#00e1ff",
    "variables": "#ff8800"
  },
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, however no matter what theme you choose, the behavior is always the same, the semantic highlighting simply stops working except when I edit it manually as you mentioned through the settings.json. What I would like is that this does not happen to me and the semantic highlighting works normally, or failing that, obtain the default configuration that is shown when it works normally to be able to enter it manually in the settings.json. Thanks

Comment: @pyGisServer Can you try to delete this folder on your computer: C:\Users\${UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Code? If it still not work can you try to reinstall the VSCode?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I also tried that. Practically all the tips related to the subject that are collected both on this page and on github I have been trying without luck. It only occurs to me to take advantage of the fact that when I edit the semantic highlighting configuration in settings.json it does respond correctly and therefore force the colors there, but I would like to use pylance's default color configuration but I have not found it

Comment: @pyGisServer Can you try to disable all the extensions but without Python related extensions to make a try?

Comment: I only have the python extension installed (and its dependencies)

Comment: @pyGisServer Can you try to update and reinstall the VSCode? If it is not the problem related to the extensions it could be some problems related to VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue for myself by enabling pylance. I had disabled it for another project that had a linking issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).